# Tracking d3.zoom transform across page refresh

Tags: d3.js

I'm having a problem with tracking Transforms across page loads, any help much appreciated.

'workspaceDiv' is a full page outer *div*

'squaregroup' is a *g* that contains all page elements and can be moved around

For this example I've added a single circle to the squaregroup

```
workspaceDiv = d3.select("#workspaceDiv")

squaregroup = workspaceDiv.append("g")
    .attr("id", "squaregroup")

squaregroup.append("circle").attr("cx", 20).attr("cy", 20).attr("r", 10);
```

To allow the user to move the *g* around the page I've attached a d3.zoom.

```
workspaceDiv.call(zoom);       
         
var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .on("zoom", zoomed)


function zoomed(){  
    squaregroup.attr("transform",  d3.event.transform)           
}
```

You might have noticed that I want to transform *squaregroup* but I have attached the d3.zoom to the *workspaceDiv*.  This is so you can transform it by clicking *anywhere* on the page (and not only by clicking in the small squaregroup).

On initial page load, this works perfect. Any transforms are also saved as a string in the URL successfully.

On a page reload, the transform is taken from the URL and applied to the sqauregroup:

```
squaregroup.attr("transform",  d3.zoomIdentity.translate(url.x,url.y).scale(url.scale))
```

Chrome devtools showing the custom transform applied after page reload
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H93Nf.png

**The problem**

After a page reload, squaregroup is transformed (see image above), but the d3.event.transform of workspaceDiv is reset, meaning the *first* drag (of 1 pixel), resets transform (to 0,0) and not with the transform I've applied (200,400).

So the 2nd+ drag is fine, but the first drag throws all data off the page meaning you have to drag around until you find it.

**Approaches**

Attaching ".call(zoom)" on *g* means the draggable area is too small, and completely changes the behaviour for the user

I can't find a way to force update the tracking of a .event to be in sync after a page reload

I'm not sure if my approach is wrong, or if there is a function of d3.zoom I just can't find.  Any input welcomed!

Many Thanks

Comment: try to call squaregroup.call(zoom) instead of workspaceDiv.call(zoom); If it does not work, please provide a fiddle with the code

Comment: Current project (first drag broken, second drag fine)
https://jsfiddle.net/AndyShepherd/cs689kb3/2/

Comment: Changing ".call(zoom)" to squaregroup  (all clicks weird, and you can only drag the circle, you can't pan the entire page)
https://jsfiddle.net/AndyShepherd/cs689kb3/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution (see it in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrovinsky/r8t9qa53/))

Make sure you are using **zoomIdentity** according to the **D3 V5** and higher (the sample you tried to use is probably done for the previous versions):

```
const svg = d3.select('svg');
const group = svg.append('g');
group.append('circle').attr('r', 20);

const zoom = d3.zoom();
const onZoom = () => group.attr('transform', d3.event.transform);

zoom.on("zoom", onZoom);
svg.call(zoom);  

const transform = d3.zoomIdentity;
transform.x = 100;
transform.y = 50;
group.call(zoom.transform, transform);
```

Comment: Amazing

For anyone else reading, I reversed it a bit, and my problem was:
- squaregroup.attr("transform", d3.zoomIdentity.translate(200,400).scale(1))
+ squaregroup.call(zoom.transform, transform);

Thankyou thankyou thankyou Michael!